# Nested url queries in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making this choose your own adventure page and I'm using form_tag to accept user input. At the start of this page a user will enter a number through this text field

```
<% choice_1a = "1" %>
<% choice_1b = "2" %>

<%= form_tag("/pathfinder/quest1", method: "get") do %>
  <center><%= text_field_tag(:a, @input_1, maxlength: 1) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %></center>
<% end %>

<% input_1 = @input_1 %> 

<% if input_1 == choice_1a %>
  **Run code if user entered 1 **
  <%= form_tag("/pathfinder/quest1", method: "get") do %>
    <center><%= text_field_tag(:b, @input_2, maxlength: 1) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %></center>
  <% end %>
<% elsif input_1 == choice_1b %>
  **Run code if user entered 2 **
<% else %>
  ** Prompt user to enter a 1 or 2**
<% end %>
```

Which results in this output in the url of the query "a" equaling whatever input was given. In this case I entered one ("&a=1")

https://192.168.0.200:3000/pathfinder/quest1?utf8=**checkmark symbol**&a=1&commit=Submit

After that path is taken they are given another form_tag that shown as below

**Path if 1 was chosen at form_tag "a"**

```
<%= form_tag("/pathfinder/quest1", method: "get") do %>
   <center><%= text_field_tag(:b, @input_2, maxlength: 1) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Submit") %></center>
<% end %>
```

When they enter a number here the url would change to this. Note how "a" was replaced with "b".

https://192.168.0.200:3000/pathfinder/quest1?utf8=**checkmark symbol**&b=1&commit=Submit

I was hoping to somehow nest these queries so that if a=1 I can have the user set the input to "b" it would still reflect their previous input to "a"

Here's a partial of the show section of the pathfinder controller that this code is running off

**Controller code**

```
 if url == ('/pathfinder/quest1')
        if params[:a].present?
            @input_1 = "#{params[:a]}"
        elsif params[:b].present?
            @input_2 = "#{params[:b]}"
        end
        render 'quest1/index'
```

What I'm trying to do is give the user the option to set a=1 and then under that branch allow b to set 1 or 2. An example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
   a=1 (being one path)       or          a=2(being the other path)
        |                                            |
        V                                            V
  b=1 <---> b=2                               c=1 <-----> c=2
  **Different paths if the user were to set "a" to one or two**
```

If the user set "a" equal to one, they would have the option of setting "b" to one or two. The same concept would be for "a" equal to two where the user would only have the option of setting "c" to one or two.

I'm open to any other ideas that doesn't require changing the url if its through html, css or javascript

Comment: You could submit *both* `a` & `b` or `a` & `c`? Once the user decides the value of `a`, have it as a hidden element in the second form that you will present.

Comment: When you mean a hidden element could this be done in a certain form_tag with rails or something with another language?